# PLSQL: How to update and Insert together when match found between source and target table

Tags: oracle11g

I have a source and a target table. I need to make update and insert together in final table with following conditions:

1) When SourceTable.ProductName = TargetTable.ProductName and SourceTable.Amount = TargetTable.Amount Then
Update TargetTable set TargetTable.ValidFrom = sysdate
Also i need to insert like this,
Insert Into TargetTable(ProductName,Amount,ValidFrom,Version) Values(TargetTable.ProductName,TargetTable.Amount, sysdate, TargetTable.Version + 1)
This is to maintain version.

2) When there is no match then i need to insert directly like this,
Insert Into TargetTable(ProductName,Amount,ValidFrom,Version) Values(SourceTable.ProductName,SourceTable.Amount, sysdate,1)

As of now i am thinking of capturing these matching records in a Cursor and perform Update and Insert together in cursor loop. But i am willing to avoid loops a i have approx 10 millions of matching records.

We also have Merge statement, but I believe Merge do not support Update and Insert together in single "WHEN MATCHED" Clause. Please correct me if i am wrong?

Kindly suggest the best way to achieve this behavior.

Comment: `I believe Merge do not support Update and Insert together in single WHEN MATCHED Clause. Please correct me if i am wrong?` = wrong. A MERGE can perform both inserts and updates, if something is matched that means it can be updated, if it is not matched then it can be inserted.

Comment: @Used_By_Already I mean can we write MERGE statement like this,
MERGE INTO TargetTable
USING(SourceTable.ProductName = TargetTable.ProductName and SourceTable.Amount = TargetTable.Amount)
WHEN MATCHED Then 
Update TargetTable set TargetTable.ValidFrom = sysdate 
Insert Into TargetTable(ProductName,Amount,ValidFrom,Version) Values(TargetTable.ProductName,TargetTable.Amount, sysdate, TargetTable.Version + 1) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED Then 
Insert Into TargetTable(ProductName,Amount,ValidFrom,Version) Values(SourceTable.ProductName,SourceTable.Amount, sysdate,1)

Kindly suggest..

Comment: Thanks @Used_By_Already for your response. Actually i have to perform both UPDATE and INSERT together WHEN MATCHED.

Comment: You have to use stored procedure to incorporate this logic.